# Hashmap in each mapper should be used in a single reducer

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, reduce

In one of my class im using HashMap.Im calling that class inside my mapper. So now each mapper has its own HashMap. Now can i use all the HashMaps into a single reducer? Actually my HashMap contains Key as my filename and value is the Set.So each HashMap contains a filename and a Set. Now i want to use all the HashMap caontaining same filename and want to club all the values(Sets) and then write that HashMap into my Hdfs file

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that. If your mapper is giving an output in the form of hashmap then you can use Hadoop's `MapWritable` as your value of mapper.
For e.g.

```
public class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, MapWritable>
```

you have to convert your `Hashmap` into `MapWritable` format:

```
MapWritable mapWritable = new MapWritable();
for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : yourHashMap.entrySet()) {
    if(null != entry.getKey() && null != entry.getValue()){
       mapWritable.put(new Text(entry.getKey()),new Text(entry.getValue()));
    }
}
```

Then provide the mapwritable to your context:

```
ctx.write(new Text("my_key",mapWritable);
```

For Reducer class you have take `MapWritable` as your input value

```
public class MyReducer extends Reducer<Text, MapWritable, Text, Text>

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<MapWritable> values, Context ctx) throws IOException, InterruptedException
```

Then iterate through the map and extract the values the way you want. For e.g:

```
for (MapWritable entry : values) {
  for (Entry<Writable, Writable> extractData: entry.entrySet()) {
      //your logic for the data will go here.
   }                    
}
```